# If the number is preceded with 0's then it has to add spaces in that position

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the next odd and even digit of a given number.For example if the first number is 9278, then the second number is 1490.But if the number is started with "8" for eg:"847" then  " 47" will be the output. If 8 is a digit it has to print 0.But the number is started with any number of "8's" it has to add spaces instead of printing 0's.

```
String number=String.valueOf(num);
        for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++)
        {
            int j=Character.digit(number.charAt(i),10);

            if(j%2==0)
            {
                int k=j+2;
                if(k>=10)
                    k=0;
                System.out.print(k);
            }
            if(j%2!=0)
            {
                int l=j+2;
                if(l>=10)
                    l=1;
                System.out.print(l);
            }
        }
```

This code prints "0361" when i give the input as "8149". But for me it has to print " 361".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that a `char` range 0-9 is corresponding to an `int`

Let define an array hold all the digits:

```
char[] digits = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1'};
```

And use just `char` to calculate the next number, no conversion or if/else needed:

```
String number = String.valueOf(num);
char[] out = new char[number.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    out[i] = digits[number.charAt(i) - '0'];
}

int leadingZeroIndex = 0;
while (out[leadingZeroIndex] == '0') {
    out[leadingZeroIndex] = ' ';
    leadingZeroIndex++;
}

System.out.println(String.valueOf(out));
```

Comment: So why not just define the array as `{'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1'}` to begin with? Also, how does this solve the OP? The problem is that for initial 8s, it should be a space rather than a zero.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, you made the point. I've updated the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to handle all scenarios:

```
boolean notRemoved = true;
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {

   // ...

   if (k == 0 && notRemoved) {
     System.out.print(String.valueOf(k).replaceFirst("[0]", " "));
   } else {
     System.out.print(k);
     notRemoved = false;
   }

   if (j % 2 != 0) {
      int l = j + 2;
      if (l >= 10)
         l = 1;
         System.out.print(l);
         notRemoved = false;
      } 
   }
}
```

Test Cases

- When `number = 1888`, output is `3000`
- When `number = 8149`, output is `_361`
- When `number = 8886`, output is `___8`
- When `number = 8286`, output is `_408`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concat the outputs to a `String` value and print the `int` value at the end. Like:

```
    String number=String.valueOf(num);
    String answer = "";
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++)
    {
        int j=Character.digit(number.charAt(i),10);
         if(num/10==8)
        {
            j=0;
        }
        if(j%2==0)
        {
            int k=j+2;
            if(k>=10)
                k=0;
            answer += (k);
        }
        if(j%2!=0)
        {
            int l=j+2;
            if(l>=10)
                l=1;
            answer += (l);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(answer));
```

Having `Integer.parseInt(answer)` in the end will remove any number of leading zeros in the `answer` string.